# How to use multiple values in when (Evaluate)? - PeopleCode

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I have the following code and as can be seen that in both the cases I'm using Section = A. But, is there a way to check both 1&2 in "When" so that to avoid more lines of code?

```
Evaluate INTERFACE
When "1"
   SECTION = "A";
   Break;
When "2"
   SECTION = "A";
   Break;
```

Any help is highly appreciated and please remember I'm still, learning. Thanks! :)

Comment: So when you looked at the **manual**, which documents the **syntax** of the `Evaluate` statement, what did you find? Assuming that you did look at the manual, and found that you can't, why ask here? Assuming that you *didn't* look, that's why you got lots of down-votes, because *"this question does not show any research effort"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all: Your code does not really look like Java, C or Cpp, and it has nothing to do with OOP, so correct the tags.

To the question:
After a quick search for `Evaluate-When` it seems like COBOL (see [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6SG3_3.4.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_3.4/tpaid02.htm)) with the same attributes as the well-known `switch-case`.

In `switch-case` you can not really have `OR`statements, but you can assign multiple values to the same block by not using the `break`:

```
char c = 'a';
switch(c){
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        fooA(); //'a' AND 'A' will land here
        break;
    case 'b':
        fooSmallB(); //only 'b' lands here
    case 'B':
        fooB(); //'b' AND 'B' lands here
        break;
    default:
        fooDef(); //Everything that does not hit any case lands here
}
```

This simulates an OR-statement. And is not possible.

EDIT:
I see now, the language is peoplecode. Never heard of that before, but documentation shows: Evaluate-When is not much different than Switch-Case

Nevertheless: There is nearly always a better possibilities than `switch-case`, see 1st comment from Michael [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883113/java-switch-statement-is-or-and-possible).

Comment: Apparently it's [peoplecode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tpcl/langref_PeopleCodeBuilt-inFunctionsandLanguageConstructs-073e6a.html).

Comment: Thanks everyone :) and sorry for the basic question. Hopefully i will learn soon and won't be bothering with wrong tags. Thanks once again!

Comment: never heard of peoplecode before. But reading the [docu](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tpcd/concept_Statements-074b4d.html) it's nearly the same as any other switch/case...

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax and the `Evaluate` statement belongs to [PeopleCode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PeopleCode) programming language which used in Oracle ERP `PeopleSoft`

Evaluate is similar to switch/case statement and here is the example how you can use it correctly in PeopleCode according to your given scenario.

```
Evaluate &yourVariable
When = "1"
When = "2"
   Warning "Value is either 1 or 2";
   Break;
When = "3"
   Warning "Value is 3";
   Break;
When = "4"
   Warning "Value is 4";
   Break;
When-Other
   Warning "Unexpected value."
End-Evaluate;
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41633_01/pt853pbh1/eng/pt/tpcd/concept_Statements-074b4d.html) is the detailed official documentation about PeopleCode evaluate statement.